# UK visitor visa: I have not received the courier UPS label yet. How can I get the label? Applying from the US

Tags: usa, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have paid for two way courier service with VFS but have not received the label yet.
When will it be generated ? I have bio metric appointment in a week. Will I get it after the biometric appointment is done?

Comment: We do not know which country you are. In any case, did you check the VFS website? (I saw similar questions in FAQs for various visas around the world, so I expect you find something there). Note: if you find something, please answer yourself this question (for next users, maybe specify the country you live): it is encouraged in this site to answer your questions when you have the answers.